# how do I enter dirac bra-ket notation in GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot

How do I enter dirac bra-ket notation for label in gnu plot with

`set term post eps enhanced color "Arial" 11`

`set output "1.eps"`

Similar to

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Symbol no. 361! E.g.:

```
set label '|1,0{/Symbol \361}' at 1,2
```

(or `xlabel`, or `title` ect...)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In this case it's probably best to use the `epslatex` terminal so that you can use full latex capabilities:

```
s(x) = 1./sqrt(2.*pi) * exp(-x**2/2.)
set term epslatex standalone header '\usepackage{amsmath}'
set output 'plot.tex'
set xlabel '$r$'
set ylabel 'WF amplitude'
plot s(x) title '$\langle 1s | r \rangle \langle r | 1s \rangle$'
```

And just run `latex` or `pdflatex`:

```
pdflatex plot.tex
```

The above looks like this:

[image]