# How to write expectation value symbols in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I need to write one of my axis label as $\langle\alpha\rangle$. I don't know how to get this Dirac notation in gnuplot. Can someone help.

Comment: you could use for example the `lua tikz` terminal, let Gnuplot generate the tex source and then compile it with for example `pdflatex`...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/36884397/2604213

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to use Gnuplot as a "pre-processing" tool in order to generate a template which is then compiled with LaTeX. To this end, consider for example following Gnuplot script:

```
set terminal lua tikz size 8cm,6cm clip background rgb '#ffffff'
set output 'frame.tex'

set xr [0:10]
set yr [0:10]

set xtics out nomirror
set ytics out nomirror

set key bottom right reverse spacing 2 width 2

set xlabel '$\langle\alpha\rangle$'
set ylabel '$f(\langle\alpha\rangle)$'
plot x t '$f(\langle\alpha\rangle)$'
```

When supplied to Gnuplot, it produces a file `frame.tex`. However, this is not a standalone LaTeX document, just the plot itself rendered with the famous TikZ package. Nevertheless, it is rather straightforward to embed it in a document as:

```
\documentclass[aip,jcp,reprint,amsmath,12pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,papersize={8cm,6cm},headheight=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz, fp, scalefnt, ifthen}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{widetext}
\input{frame.tex}%
\end{widetext}
\end{document}
```

If this file is called for example `figure.tex`, then `pdflatex figure.tex` produces:

[image]

Comment: For simplicity you can use `set terminal tikz standalone ...`

Comment: @Christoph indeed, the "embedding" of the Gnuplot output into an additional document perhaps unnecessarily complicates things. However, it also has its advantages, I have been using this solution in order to generate figures for scientific papers since then one can use for example `\cite` commands directly in the plot legend